# How to execute a wordpress function inside custom PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Inside my active theme there is a user.php which serves this kind of url http://mysite.com/user/username. Inside user.php I echo a script tag with the following content

```
$.ajax({ url: "' . get_theme_root_uri() . '/fray/userslogan.php",
                    data: {"id": ' . $profile['id'] . ', "slogan": el.innerHTML},
                    type: "post",
                    success: function(status) { alert(status); }                    
                });
```

I created a file userslogan.php and added it at the same level as user.php. Inside this file now all I want to do is

```
<?php
update_user_meta( $_POST['id'], 'slogan', $_POST['slogan'] );
echo 1;
?>
```

but I get errors that functions that I call are undefined. So if I include some file that defines the update_user_meta function, then I will get another similar error and so on. What is the right way of executing code like this?

Comment: try this: include("../../../wp-load.php");

Comment: Check this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47059/26906

Comment: You should not use own files to make ajax calls you should do it the WordPress way: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `WP AJAX`

1) http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

2) http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

function my_action_javascript() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
    action: 'my_action',
    whatever: 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
  });
  </script>
  <?php
  }

  add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

   function my_action_callback() {
global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

$whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

$whatever += 10;

    echo $whatever;

die(); // this is required to return a proper result
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `wp-load.php` to get access to the wordpress function in custom files.

Suggestion: [Don’t include wp-load, please.](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) Use ajax in wordpress in proper way. You can refer this [article](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/).

**From above article**

> Why this is wrong
>
> 1. You don’t have the first clue where wp-load.php actually is. Both the plugin directory and the wp-content directory can be moved around
>      in the installation. ALL the WordPress files could be moved about in
>      this manner, are you going to search around for them?
> 2. You’ve instantly doubled the load on that server. WordPress and the PHP processing of it all now have to get loaded twice for every page
>      load. Once to produce the page, and then again to produce your
>      generated javascript.
> 3. You’re generating javascript on the fly. That’s simply crap for caching and speed and such.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the entire Wordpress codebase in there. Your best bet would be to make an actual Wordpress plugin, that's going to be a lot easier than this.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin